# Passing a callback function to a prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Experimenting with a messaging module that will provide methods for emitting and listening to events between several modules in a Node app. Fairly new to this endeavor. My goal is to initialize a listener and have it feed directly into a callback function.

Getting tripped up on syntax and JS prototyping at this point.

```
var events = require('events');
var inter_com = new events.EventEmitter();


var com_bus = {
  initListener:function(listener_name, callback){
    this.listener_name = listener_name;
    this.callback_function = callback;
    inter_com.on(this.listener_name, this.callback_function);
  },
  sendMessage:function(data){
    inter_com.emit(this.listener_name,data);
    console.log('test event sent');
  }
}

var instance_of_com = Object.create(com_bus);
instance_of_com.initListeners('testing',pipeMe);
instance_of_com.sendMessage('its good to be the king');


var pipeMe = function(data){console.log(data)};`
```

Comment: Based on suggested patterns, I put together two gists: https://gist.github.com/Digi-D/9dc9197634a72904e033  and https://gist.github.com/Digi-D/3c53a56053e62779e56c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript follows prototypal inheritance ,

1) To inherit from an object , parent need to be a Function.Convention is that function should be named as `InitCap` , that denotes it's a constructor.

2) Also child inherits the prototype so instead of inheriting from `Function_Name` you need to inherit from `Function_Name.prototype`.

```
var events = require('events');
var inter_com = new events.EventEmitter();

function Com_bus() {

}

Com_bus.prototype.initListeners = function(listener_name, callback) {
    this.listener_name = listener_name;
    this.callback_function = callback;
    inter_com.on(this.listener_name, this.callback_function);
};

Com_bus.prototype.sendMessage = function(listener_name, callback) {
    inter_com.emit(this.listener_name, data);
    console.log('test event sent');
};

var pipeMe = function(data) {
    console.log(data)
};

var instance_of_com = Object.create(Com_bus.prototype);
instance_of_com.initListeners('testing', pipeMe);
instance_of_com.sendMessage('its good to be the king');
```

Comment: Thank you. This straightened out some ideas about prototypal inheritance in JS that I am still trying to digest.

Answer (score 1):

one way to solve this is to create a factory which returns an instance of com_bus:

```
function returnComBusInstance () {
    // create a closure on these variables
    var listener_name;
    var callback_function;
    return {
        initListener:function(_listener_name, _callback){
            listener_name = _listener_name;
            callback_function = _callback;
            inter_com.on(listener_name, callback_function);
        },
        sendMessage:function(data){
             inter_com.emit(listener_name, data);
             console.log('test event sent');
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var com_bus_instance = returnComBusInstance()
```

I personally try to avoid using `this` but if you need to then you can either, `bind`, `call`, or `apply`, or again you could create a factory but create a closure on the context of `this`

Or you could pass in prototype properties to `Object.create`:

```
Object.create(com_bus, {
    'listener_name': {value: null, enumerable:true},    
    'callback_function': {value:null, enumerable:true}
});
```

Comment: Great pattern! Thank you. Went with a more "classical" solution to the problem because the rest of the code base is already written this way but definitely learning the factory approach as it seems to better leverage the good points of JS.